# Grizzly set headers on static assets

Tags: java, http-headers, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I have a jersey2 + Grizzly REST framework setup. In addition to dynamic operations, I also have class loader handlers to serve my static assets for my ui, such as css, js etc.  I'd like to be able to set response headers on these to control things like caching on the browser etc.  I'm not sure how to hook this into the grizzly framework though.

I do something like this:

```
CLStaticHttpHandler myHandler = new CLStaticHttpHandler(Main.class.getClassLoader(), "ui/");
    myHandler.setFileCacheEnabled(true);
    httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(myHandler, "/ui");
```

to get my static handler setup.  Any ideas for how I hook in and set response header for these static assets?